# Tried styling order print page, but css is not active. What do i do wrong

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, css, print

So a customer registers and creates an account. They order something (at least, they should ;-))

After that they can visit their My Account > My Orders and select to print an order, shipment or whatever is in there.

When this action is performed on screen you are presented with the e.g. invoice (and a print dialog)

i added styling for this page to custom.css but it is not used.

Where would i need to do this or do i need to add something in a certain file?

Thanks

Comment: there is no custom.css included in that page, try changing print.css

Comment: ok i'll try to do that... but i'd rather have a pdf instead i guess

Comment: styling pdf will not be easy if you are considering that just because of this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom css to print layout handle in a custom layout.xml or the sales.xml for example:

```
<sales_order_print>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom_print.css</name></action>
    </reference>
</sales_order_print>
```

Comment: thanks, would i need to copy sales.xml (or layout.xml - which is best?) from app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml (haven't found layout.xml ;P) to app/design/frontend/mytheme/child/layout/sales.xml and just add that code you provide above? and after that add file custom_print.css to skin/design/frontend/mytheme/child/css/ ?

Comment: when i add my print css to theme/child/css/styles.css it is visible on screen... when i add print.css in that folder with same css it is not read although it is in head, but i don't think that is the right way ;-) it would be best if i could get the styling from custom.css

Comment: when copying the sales.xml, yes, the steps you described. if you add a file in `theme/child/css/` with the name print.css you will override all styles in the print.css loaded from the default `theme/default/css`. The best way is to name it like custom_print.css or something. So you can avoid any inheritance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom print stylesheet in your `skin/frontend/<your_theme>/default/css` and name it something like `custom_print.css` to avoid any conflicts.

Now you can either target specific sections in the previous solution or you can place it in the head section of `page.xml` so it is available site-wide. I.e. as a child node of `head`:

`<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom_print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>`